# trigger for conserved functional dependence between two attributs on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this relation `R( A , B , C , D )`

[relation R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ww1f.png)

B --- >  C ,D  mean that a value of B give us unique value of C and unique value of D

### A  |  B  |  C |  D

### 1  |  1  |  1 |  1

### 2  |  5  |  2 |  3

### 3  |  1  |  1 |  1

### 6  |  5  |  2 |  3

### 9  |  8  |  1 |  1

### 10 |  8  |  1 |  1

as you can see when B=1  we have C=1 and D=1 , when B=5 we have C=2 AND D=3
when B=8  we have C=1 AND D=1

I want to create a trigger on MySQl to preserve functional dependence
between B --> C,D

i've created this trigger change values of B,C,D to NULL  but it seems not a good solution can you give me a trigger refuse the row

```
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS DF;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER DF BEFORE INSERT ON R
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    # main trigger part
    if(exists(select * from R where NEW.B=B AND (NEW.C!=C OR  NEW.D!=D)))
    THEN 
    SET NEW.B=NULL ; SET NEW.C=NULL ; SET NEW.D=NULL ;
    END IF ;
END ;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What do you mean with conserved functional dependence betweem B --> C,D..  you should give some example data.. some input and expected results.. Reverse engineering your trigger code will not explain your question.

Comment: i have added exemples see it

Comment: add the example as text data tables not a image.. We can't work with a image.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can do this with unique constraints, rather than triggers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  it's just a challenge can i do it with triggers

Comment: It would be more normal to have a 3rd table, with just `B, C, D` in it, with `B` being the unique primary key.  This way you only ever insert `B` in to the table `R`.  In this way it becomes impossible to create a conflict.

Comment: @MatBailie this is not real case " just challenge"

Comment: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,99214,99300#msg-99300  This would refuse the whole insert *(you can't refuse just one row in a multi row insert)* and the error returned would be misleading *(failure due to conflict reported as failure due to NULLs)*.